# Use database from annotation.php file to create dynamic routes in symfony

Tags: php, symfony4

I am trying to create a dynamic router for my symfony application where on a base of some condition I want to set the prefix of a route, the condition based prefix is working as I use the statically coded condition, see my router with dummy route, main symfony route for Bundle

(config/routes/annotation.php)

```
<?php use Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\Configurator\RoutingConfigurator;
    return function (RoutingConfigurator $routes) {
    $resultRout = $routes->import('@MyCustomBundle/Controller/Test/', 'annotation')
    ->defaults(['_locale' => '%locale%'])
    ->requirements(['_locale' => '%app_locales%']);
    // get $validate value from database
    if ($validate) {
        $resultRout->prefix('/{_locale}/app/{default_path}/');
    } else {
        $resultRout->prefix('/{_locale}/site/{new_path}/');
    }
};
```

The issues I face are:

**1**: I need to clear route caching every time for different route condition. Is there a way to stop route caching?

**2**: I want to access database so that I can create $validate as per the DB values. How to load entity manager?

Also if there is a better way to achieve this type of routing please suggest.

Comment: [Symfony CMF](http://cmf.symfony.com/) has a [bundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/bundles/routing/introduction.html) that adds a router with database-support. Maybe it can help.

Comment: @msg thanks, I will check and will get back